# 1mm-long insect ID from Tennessee

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in east Tennessee. I went outside today (May 27.2017) and saw all these tiny insects all over my truck.

They are yellowish in color and have 6 legs, one solid body (including head). They move pretty quickly (like a chigger)

What are they?

[image: Tree insects]

[image]

Comment: `East TN` you said. Does TN stands for Tenessee or Tunisia (both being typically abbreviated TN)?

Comment: Very important to mention that they are six-legged.

Comment: @adjan and I are being a bit mocking today! Sorry about that. I edited the post assuming that you live in Tunisia (given your user name and given that a Tunisian would probably name the country fully by fear people would not understand). I  also removed the (quasi-) tautology (6-legged insect). +1

Comment: @Remi.b "I edited the post assuming that you live in Tunisia." *"I live in east Tennessee."* ;)

Comment: That was a typo.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I know that computer graphics are difficult, but the photos you have posted do not display in my browser because they are about 10 times larger than necessary and do not show enough detail. I have processed the first for you, but if you need to post again, do an internet search to find out how to downsize photos.

Comment: The only reason I uploaded the large photos is so that you could zoom in and see the insects better, (The better to see you with my dear ((Wolf))

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, yes, east tennessee

Comment: I thought it might have been a Thrip, wasnt sure about that

Comment: Include the size (approx is ok) in question. maybe 1mm or half-mm? Best if include the size (height or width) of reference,  "SRF" logo, which is easily measurable.

Answer (score 2):

The insects you have found must be of a species of [thrips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips). This excerpt from Wikipedia fits your description well:

> **Thrips** (order *Thysanoptera*) are minute (1 mm long or less), slender insects with fringed wings and unique asymmetrical mouthparts. Different thrips species feed, mostly on plants although a few are predators, by puncturing and sucking up the contents. Approximately 6,000 species have been described.

I won't try to identify the exact species, but here is a photo of a yellowish-orange thrip I have found:

[image]

**Image source:**

https://6legs2many.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/thysanoptera_thrips_fringe_wings.jpg